# Change text in a lexical editor using chomre extension

Tags: button, click, edit, innerhtml, using

I am attempting to create a Chrome extension that can input text into a text box automatically when a user clicks a button. I've experimented with different approaches like using innerHTML and textContent, but I'm wondering if there's a specific function designed for updating text within the DOM that I could use when the button is clicked. Despite trying various methods like innerHTML and textContent, I've faced issues with applying an update using the querySelector on a div element. Are there any functions I could call upon clicking the button to achieve this more effectively?